# Update identity column to maintain unique number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have a table to maintain the next available unique number for a specific use-case in our application. We thought of having a column of type bigint which will be incremented and provide the next available number. Is it possible to make this column as identity column and auto-increment the same row?

I found a link on stackoverflow [Usage of Table with single column (Identity)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607476/usage-of-table-with-single-column-identity) with similar requirements. However the solution mentioned would insert a new record in the table. Instead of insert, i would like to do an update on same record to keep track of next available unique number.

Is it possible to leverage Identity column feature or I would need to fetch the current value, explicitly increment and store it back into the same row in same column?

Comment: You don't really need to fetch.  update table set fakeiden = fakeiden + 1

Comment: Is there something specific in your use-case that would prohibit the identity column from being defined within the table, as suggested by @Philiop?

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. I can define identity column in my table. However I was not able to update the same row and keep track of the next available number.  I also found [SEQUENCE object in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) which is another possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a Stored Procedure to start a transaction, increment the stored bigint (not an identity) and return the new value, rolling back the transaction if anything goes wrong.

The update section of the SP would be **like** (can't test atm):

```
DECLARE @RET TABLE (Value BigInt)

UPDATE Mytable
SET MyField += 1
OUTPUT inserted.MyField INTO @RET

IF (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM @RET) > 0
RETURN (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM @RET)
```

[OUTPUT Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564.aspx)

This would make only 1 write to the table and return the new value.
Checking the value will return the last value issued.

Comment: Thanks bendataclear. Your solution worked for me. However I received a   syntax error while executing above mentioned statements. I modified the update statement as `UPDATE Mytable
 SET MyField += 1
 OUTPUT INSERTED.MyField INTO @RET`

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I've updated the answer to the correct order in case it can help anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. Believe your just after an identy adding i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (rowName BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)
```

This would create a table with a column called rowName which auto increments by one.

Comment: Instead of insert, i would like to do an update on same record to keep track of next available unique number.